# Javascript reduce, cant handle array of object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to handle this rule on an array of objects
if there is one or more objects with type equal landline return the first number else if there are no objects with type = landline return the first number only if its type property is different than mobile, in the case its equal to mobile return the next number if available otherwise return a blank value

```js
var phoneObject = [
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    phone: '0123456789'
  },
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    number:'78945610'
  }
  {
    type:'landline'
    number:'15975345'
  }
];

var number = phoneObject.reduce((a,b)=>{
  if (a.type === 'landline' && b.type === 'landline') {
    b.number = a.number;
  }
  else {
    if (a.type !== 'landline' && b.type !== 'landline') {
      if (a.type !== 'mobile') {
        b.number = a.number;
      } else {
        if (b.number) {
          return b.number;
        }
        else {
          b.number = '';
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return b.number;
});
console.log(number);
```

```js
// should return the third number for this array
var phoneObject = [
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    phone: '0123456789'
  },
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    number:'78945610'
  }
  {
    type:'landline'
    number:'15975345'
  }
];


// for this one it should return the first 
var phoneObject = [
  {
    type: 'landline',
    phone: '0123456789'
  },
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    number:'78945610'
  }
  {
    type:'landline'
    number:'15975345'
  }
];

// for this one it should return the second number
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    phone: '0123456789'
  },
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    number:'78945610'
  }
];

// and for this last one it should return a blank value
var phoneObject = [
  {
    type: 'mobile',
    phone: '0123456789'
  },
];
```

thanks for your help
Best Regards,
Sarah

Comment: I think you are imagining the parameters of `.reduce()` working like the parameters in `.sort()`, which, if you are using objects *can* be the case, but in your example, a.number starts out as undefined, and ends up setting `b.number = undefined`, then you are returning a number, which becomes `a`. The next iteration, you call a.number, which of course is undefined, so you set b.number = undefined again, and the cycle continues. I will post an answer shortly

Comment: Along the line of what mhodges pointed out, the first parameter to `reduce` is the *accumulator* parameter: its whatever was returned by the previous invocation of the reducing function. For the first iteration, it uses the supplied value: so always supply an initial value to `reduce`!

Comment: why `number` and `phone`?

Comment: error from me it should be number, thanks for your helps guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do some decent checks and save the second number. Use it only if not a landline number is present.

This proposal works with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function getNumber(array) {
    var counter = 0,
        second = '';
    return array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (r) {
            return r;
        }
        if (o.type === 'landline') {
            return o.number;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter === 2) {
            second = o.number;
        }
    }, '') || second;
}

//should return the third number for this array
var phoneObject1 = [{ type: 'mobile',  number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }, { type: 'landline', number:'15975345' }];

// for this one it should return the first 
var phoneObject2 = [{ type: 'landline', number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }, { type:'landline', number:'15975345' }];

// for this one it should return the second number
var phoneObject3 = [{ type: 'mobile', number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }];

//and for this last one it should return a blank value
var phoneObject4 = [{ type: 'mobile', number: '0123456789' }];

console.log([phoneObject1, phoneObject2, phoneObject3, phoneObject4].map(getNumber));
```

The same, as above, but with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
function getNumber(array) {
    var counter = 0,
        landline = '',
        second = '';

    array.some(function (o) {
        if (o.type === 'landline') {
            landline = o.number;
            return true;
        }
        counter++;
        if (counter === 2) {
            second = o.number;
        }
    });
    return landline || second;
}

//should return the third number for this array
var phoneObject1 = [{ type: 'mobile',  number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }, { type: 'landline', number:'15975345' }];

// for this one it should return the first 
var phoneObject2 = [{ type: 'landline', number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }, { type:'landline', number:'15975345' }];

// for this one it should return the second number
var phoneObject3 = [{ type: 'mobile', number: '0123456789' }, { type: 'mobile', number:'78945610' }];

//and for this last one it should return a blank value
var phoneObject4 = [{ type: 'mobile', number: '0123456789' }];

console.log([phoneObject1, phoneObject2, phoneObject3, phoneObject4].map(getNumber));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment but...

You forget two comma:

```
 {
type: 'mobile',
number:'78945610'
}
{
type:'landline'
number:'15975345'
}
```

Must edit to:

```
 {
type: 'mobile',
number:'78945610'
},
{
type:'landline',
number:'15975345'
}
```

Comment: The text is too long for comments.

Comment: Then mention that in the answer: "This is too long for a comment but..."